# Scrolling (using Touch Pad) not working in C# Metro Style App but It works if I choose JavaScript as language

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, scroll

I am trying to create Windows 8 Metro App First Time.
I have worked on all three (C#, VB and JavaScript) languages.
I first created `Grid App` template (JavaScript Language). Everything looks fine. Scrolling was working through touch pad (two finger scrolling) in JS.

But When I created same `Grid App` in C#. What I found Horizontal Scrolling using two finger not working. I can only scrolling by dragging scroll-bar. Size of scroll-bar (thing that I pick, not whole scroll-bar) is also variable. It is taking around half of the scroll-bar size but when I move it to the right, Its size is getting small. I don't see any such behavior if I create same `Grid App` in JavaScript language.

Is any one else is facing same problem..??

I have also seen this problem in many apps that I have installed from store like 'NDTV' and a few more. May be these are developed in C#.

How can I get two finger scrolling working in C#..??

In meanwhile I am requesting to Create a tag something like `metro-apps` who have reputation more than 1500.

Comment: This is driving me crazy on my laptop with Windows 8. In most apps, I can't scroll using the touchpad.

Comment: Are you using a Synaptics touchpad? If so, I found this: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1114081-windows-8-synaptics-touchpad-drivers/ which links to http://www.station-drivers.com/page/Synaptics.htm where I downloaded 16.3.1.2 and it fixed my problem.

Comment: I already did it.. It fixed these problem but came with another problem. Now I can not scroll inside a list (drop down list). It closes the dropdown list and scrolls in the page